# .NET port with Java's Map, Set, HashMap

Tags: c#, java

I am porting Java code in .NET and I am stuck in the following lines that (behave unexpectedly in .NET).

**Java**:

```
Map<Set<State>, Set<State>> sets = new HashMap<Set<State>, Set<State>>();

Set<State> p = new HashSet<State>();

if (!sets.containsKey(p)) { ... }
```

The equivalent **.NET** code could possibly be:

```
IDictionary<HashSet<State>, HashSet<State>> sets = new Dictionary<HashSet<State>, HashSet<State>>();

HashSet<State> p = new HashSet<State>();

 if (!sets.containsKey(p)) { /* (Add to a list). Always get here in .NET (??) */ }
```

However the code comparison fails, the program think that "sets" never contain Key "p" and eventually results in OutOfMemoryException.

Perhaps I am missing something, object equality and identity might be different between Java and .NET.

*I tried implementing IComparable and IEquatable in class State but the results were the same.*

**Edit:**

What the code does is: If the sets does not contain key "p" (which is a HashSet) it is going to add "p" at the end of a LinkedList>.

The State class (Java) is a simple class defined as:

```
public class State implements Comparable<State> {

boolean accept;
Set<Transition> transitions;

int number;
int id;

// ...

public int compareTo(State s) {
    return s.id - id;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return super.equals(obj);
}

public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}
```

Comment: Show us your code for the State class. Also, it would be great if you could explain what you want the code to do exactly (preferably in business rather than technical terms).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, the list and set implementations override `equals` etc. The equivalent *doesn't* happen in .NET. However, you can create a dictionary using an appropriate equality comparer using [`HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475.aspx) and pass it to the `Dictionary` constructor like this:

```
IDictionary<HashSet<State>, HashSet<State>> sets =
    new Dictionary<HashSet<State>, HashSet<State>>
       (HashSet<State>.CreateSetComparer());
```

This is assuming that `State` overrides `Equals/GetHashCode` and ideally implements `IEquatable<State>` too.